# How to render explosions and fire animations in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, smoke-simulation

I am trying to render a scene where I am animating an explosion and simultaneously changing the camera view. When I rendered it as an image sequence, the camera view changed as per the keyframes but the fire flame was stuck as it was in the initial frame. I am using Cycles render.
[image: A frame from the scene I have been trying to render]

The above is a frame from the scene I have been trying to render. The fire in the cooling cell is stuck as it is in every frame. It was animated to explode but that is not showing.

Comment: We will need some more information, screenshots and the .blend file would be really helpful

Comment: how about the viewport is it any different ?

Comment: @Chebhou No.. It's not any different in viewport

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise The blend file is a bit large and I'm having trouble uploading it. What other information would be helpful to you?

Comment: I believe this a smoke simulation does it run in the viewport ( solid view ) normally ?

Comment: Yes it does run in solid view

Comment: it could be the material used for the smoke

Comment: Could there be a problem in the process of rendering. I'm relatively new to this, so does fire render when you animate the camera movement or what?

Comment: Yes, it will still work as expected if set up properly, although I have noticed that sometimes if you change a setting it will freeze at the first frame in the render *and* the viewport. Does the viewport preview of the fire freeze after the render?

Comment: Here is the link to the blender file https://mega.co.nz/#!O9oDlYgY!NRi_ipdK2YEZpYavc23tBsVSiX89F9Pf_o2GU6jgu7g

Comment: @AnuragSinghania  just Bake_All_Dynamics and it will render fine ( at least for me )